# Sorting Numbers That Have 4 Divisors (java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, primes

I need to sort a range of numbers. The numbers can be from 0 to 1000. The user enters a range of numbers between 0 and 1000. So if they for example maybe enter 0 -> 500.

My goal would be to take all the numbers in the range given and output all the numbers in that range that have only 4 possible divisors (including 1 and itself.

I'm wondering if I should use an algorithm such as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm), or if I should check and int array that contains all the numbers from 1 - 1000 that are divisible by 4 (so the array doesn't have 1-1000 it has the numbers in that range that would be divisible 4 times only. Would require manual work to add all the possible divisors to that array).

I'm looking to make it efficient just I'm not sure if using such an algorithm would be very fast for this.

Comment: " if I should check and int array with the numbers 1-1000 that are divisible only 4 times". Don't understand.... I thought that is what you have to do.

Comment: Okay I tried to edit my question to clear that up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a number that's the product of two primes *edit: or the cube of a prime*. Since your numbers are small, you can just make a short table of the primes between 2 and 500.  Then, starting with 2, multiply each prime by each of the primes above it until you're over your upper limit.

Edit: Is this homework? If it is, I've probably said too much already.  If it isn't, I can provide some code or pseudocode if my answer doesn't make sense.

Edit: Thanks, Daniel Fischer: I missed the cubes of primes. You can check for and include these in your outer loop. (Before you multiply a prime by each of those above it, see if its cube falls in in the desired range.)

Generally:

```
for ( p1 is a prime in your list, except for the last) {
    if p1 cubed is in your range, add it to the answer
    for (p2 is a prime in your list greater than p1) {
        if p2*p1 is in your range, add it to the answer
        //optimization: break when you know you won't find any more
    }
}
// optimization: calculate the ranges of p1 and p2 to be included 
// before you start each loop
// (probably only worthwhile if you raise the limit to something 
// much larger than 1000)
```

It's certainly fast enough for numbers on this scale. I have it in under a millisecond (to find 292 numbers between 0 and 1000. I used hardcoded primes --- you only need 95 of them for this range of inputs.)

Comment: I actually like this way. Instead of a array of numbers that have 4 divisors, I make an array of prime numbers. I think this should work good. Thanks!

Comment: to make it efficient use the sieve algorithm for prime generation, add your numbers in a map, try adding prime1xprime2 and check if it fails

Comment: Oh I see your edit. This is just a little thing our teacher assigned for people who finished there other work already. It's not worth marks it's just more for fun. I mostly understood your answer but the way I'm thinking of doing it doesn't seem efficant once it gets to higher numbers. (check every number in the prime array, and see if would divide evenly. It would only check those half of number checking though.) If you have a better way it would be nice if you could post some pseudocode.

Comment: Rather than testing each number, I was thinking of generating the appropriate numbers.  Given the range 10..100: 2*3 is too small. 2*5, 2*7, 2*11 ... 2*47, (largest prime <= 100/2) then 3*5, 3*7 ... 3*31, 5*7, 5*11 ... and so on.  Be sure you can tell your teacher _why_ these numbers (products of two primes), and only these numbers, meet the criteria. (As a math teacher myself, I'm obligated to encourage understanding, not just getting an answer.)

Comment: I don't really understand that, all that much.

Comment: Which part? Do you see why the product of two primes has exactly 4 divisors? (Hint: pick a couple of small numbers (say 9,10, and 30), find their prime factorizations, and count their divisors.) Can you see how to find every combination of primes with a product in your desired range? (Hint: you'll want a loop inside another loop)

Comment: You have forgotten about the cubes of primes. These also have exactly four divisors.

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan Yes I understand the logic part of this I just do not understand how I could program this efficiently doing this. So far I have an array with prime numbers from 0 - 1000.

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan Okay I will give this a try, and see if I have any luck with it!

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan Okay I'm not quite sure what exactly should be in these conditions for these for loops. I don't like to be spoon fed, but I'm just not that advanced in math nor Java yet therefore it is easier said then done for me.